# Many-to-many join table, bi-directional relationships and data integrity

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have an old legacy table like this:

```
 =====================
| product1 | product2 |
 =====================
|        1 |        2 |
|        2 |        1 |
|        3 |        4 |
|        4 |        5 |
|        5 |        3 |
 =====================
```

It's a poorly designed table, I know, but it has to stay. The purpose of the table is to store relationships between products. The rule is that each product should have a reference to each similar product and vice-versa. Assuming that the example data is the full dataset, the first two rows are correct - 1 has a relationship with 2 and 2 has a relationship with 1. However, the last three rows are a mess. The correct way of representing those products' relationships would be:

```
 =====================
| product1 | product2 |
 =====================
|        3 |        4 |
|        3 |        5 |
|        4 |        3 |
|        4 |        5 |
|        5 |        3 |
|        5 |        4 |
 =====================
```

What I need is some kind of algorithm (or tool) so that I can identify and fix the incorrect data.

Comment: Oh, yes and BTW, if you don't even know how to solve such a simple problem on your own, it might be better NOT to comment at all on whether the table is "poorly designed" or not.

Answer (score 2):

That's a relatively straightforward SQL query.

SELECT product1,product2
...
WHERE its mirror row does not exist.

and that latter clause is like

NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM tbl AS MIRROR
   WHERE MIRROR.product1 = outertbl.product2
     AND MIRROR.product2 = outertbl.product1
)

If MySQL supports EXCEPT, that's another way to write the query.

Comment: No MySQL EXCEPT. There's an idiom with outer join.